# Gulp: How to set up multiple sources and destinations in one task?

Tags: gulp, gulp-imagemin

I'm using `gulp-imagemin` to minify images in my `images` folder. The output of the task should be streamed into `dist/images` directory. However, the source `images` folder has a subfolder `images/headers` whose compressed contents should be streamed to `dist/images/headers`. So this is the source folder structure:

```
-images
  -headers
```

whose contents should be streamed to:

```
-dist
  -images (contents of `images`)
    -headers (contents of `images/headers`)
```

Currently my task definition looks like this:

```
gulp.task('compress', function () {
    return gulp.src('images/*')
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
            use: [pngquant()]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
});
```

My question is how I can tell Gulp to stream `images/headers` into `dist/images/headers` without writing a separate task for it.

I know that I can pass array of sources, but then ho can I tell Gulp where to output processed contents of each destination so that each source has a different destination?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a recursive glob. Now you're only watching for changes directly in the images folder. Instead of using **gulp.src('images/*')** you should use **gulp.src('images/**')**.

Your new task will look like:

```
gulp.task('compress', function () {
    return gulp.src('images/**')
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
            use: [pngquant()]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
});
```

This will process every image located in the *images* folder and below to the *dist/images* folder.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful advice. Are you sure that the directory structure from `images/` will be reflected in `dist/images` and the contents in `images/` will not be "flattened" in the `dist/` folder? I will verify it myself, but I just wanted to stress that this is what I wanted to achieve.